# Creating an API

Tags: java, api, jar

I am working on creating an API from our website Java code for our customers to use.  I have exported the project to a JAR file in eclipse. In a separate test project, I am able to call certain methods from the JAR with correct functionality.

I am running into issues when I initiate a new Object of a class (TrackingAction) that references javax.servlet.http.HttpRequestServlet.  I get the following errors

```
The import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved
The import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved
HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type
HttpSession cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
import com.myproject.api.data.ShipmentDetail;
import com.myproject.api.data.ShipmentSummary;
import com.myproject.api.service.ShipmentService;
import com.myproject.web.project.action.TrackingAction;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ShipmentSummary shipSum = new ShipmentSummary();
        ShipmentDetail shipDet = new ShipmentDetail();

        TrackingAction trAction = new TrackingAction(); //ERROR COMES FROM THIS LINE

        ShipmentService shipServ = trAction.getShipmentService();

        List<ShipmentSummary> lss = shipServ.getShipmentSummaryByProNumber("101844564");
        List<ShipmentDetail> lsd = shipServ.getShipmentDetail(lss.get(0));

        shipDet = lsd.get(0);
        shipSum = lss.get(0);

        System.out.println("Summary status: " + shipSum.getStatus());
        System.out.println("Detail pickup: " + shipDet.getPickupNumber());
    }
}
```

I've looked all over the place and I can't find a working solution.  I've tried using ClassLoaders with no success.  I've tried OneJar, and it doesn't seem to work correctly (unless I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Are you including the servlet JAR in the classpath before running the program?

Comment: I'd guess you're doing something wrong, but it depends on what you're actually trying to do. Clearly you're missing the servlet API or implementation on the classpath during execution.

Comment: I have the servlet JAR in the classpath of my test program, yes.  It is also included in the classpath of my original code was used to make the JAR file that I am testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing classes (from your API classes) that are Enterprise Java (Servlets etc)/ Even if the project itself is not SE, it is wrong to use those from a main() method which is aimed for SE execution.

Java SE projects do not have:

- javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
- javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

The only way httpsession, servlet, etc will be available is when your running this code in a servlet with tomcat (or some other servlet container).

Refactor your classes to:

- separate your core API logic from Java EE servlet dependent code
- rewrite your servlet methods (e.g. doGet() ) to also reference and use this API.
- create a JAR with only your API logic, which you be referenced by your Java SE application and Java Servlet.